# Creating a SQL query to find recent field changes

Tags: sql, common-table-expression

I am having problems trying to create a SQL query to select the most recent change in hours and the difference from the previous time recorded.

The table is as below, the database keeps all the historical version together by versions:

```
Item    ID        Title           RevisedDate       ChangedDate       Rev      WorkHours
Task    187061    Development     10/9/12 11:14     10/5/12 15:54     1        4
Task    187061    Development     10/9/12 14:29     10/9/12 11:14     2        8
Task    187061    Development     10/10/12 15:07    10/9/12 14:29     3        16
Task    187061    Development     10/11/12 9:59     10/10/12 15:07    4        16
Task    187061    Development     10/12/12 10:51    10/11/12 9:59     5        16
Task    187061    Development     12/6/12 15:25     10/12/12 10:51    6        16
Task    187061    Development     12/11/12 10:27    12/6/12 15:25     7        16
Task    187061    Development     1/1/99 0:00       12/11/12 10:27    8        16
```

So the task most recent worked hours were updated on 10/10/12 15:07 from 8hr to 16hrs. I am having problems creating a query to tell me.

At the end of the day I need a result :-

```
Item    ID      Title           RevisedDate     ChangedDate     Rev   WorkHours   ChangeHours
Task    187061  Development     10/10/12 15:07  10/9/12 14:29   3     16          8
```

(p.s I took one task as an example, the actual table has hundreds of task and several historical version)

Comment: what do you exactly mean when you say *most recent* ? which date to take?

Answer (score 0):

As I understand your question you want the item with the most recent revised date for each ID

You get that like this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM
(
  SELECT *, 
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY RevisedDate DESC) as ord
  FROM TABLE
) T
WHERE ord = 1
```

If you want the first one that changed that is harder:

```
-- First find the ones that changed
With FlagChange AS
(
  SELECT T1.ID, T1.REV, T1.RevisedDate 
         CASE WHEN T2 IS NULL THEN FALSE
              WHEN T1.WorkHour != T2.WorkHour THEN TRUE 
              ELSE FALSE END AS Changed
  FROM TABLE T1
  LEFT JOIN TABLE T2 ON T1.ID = T2.ID AND T2.REV = T1.REV-1
), NumberChange -- now use row number
(
  SELECT ID, REV,
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY RevisedDate DESC) as ord
  FROM FlagChange
  WHERE Changed = True
), SelectRecent -- take the newest ones
(
  SELECT ID, REV
  FROM NumberChange
  WHERE ord = 1
)  -- add in all the data and the ones with one revision
SELECT *
FROM TABLE T1
JOIN SelectRecient SR ON T1.ID = SR.ID AND T1.REV = SR.REV
UNION ALL
SELECT *
FROM TABLE 
WHERE ID NOT IN (SELECT ID FROM SelectRecent)
```